# Not receiving in the golang channel

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

In the example below I am sending "ping"s to 'mq' string channel in anonymous go routine and try to receive these strings in four **dequeue()** goroutines , not sure why it doesn't print anything

```
    $ cat channels2.go 
    ...
    var mq chan string

    func main() {
            mq = make(chan string)
            for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
                    go dequeue()
            }
            go func() {
                    for i := 0; ; i++ {
                            mq <- "ping" 
                            }
            }()

    }

    func dequeue() {
            for m := range mq {
                    fmt.Println(m)
            }
    }
   $ go run channels2.go
   $
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as the main goroutine returns, the program exits. So you need to make sure to *not* return from `main` early. One way to do this is to execute the write-loop to the channel in the main goroutine:

```
var mq chan string

func main() {
        mq = make(chan string)
        for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
                go dequeue()
        }
        for {
            mq <- "ping" 
        }
}

func dequeue() {
        for m := range mq {
                fmt.Println(m)
        }
}
```